# Why am I getting a syntax error in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.grouped_elements").fancybox(
       'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
       'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
       'speedIn' : 600,
       'speedOut' : 200, 
       'overlayShow' : false );
  });
</script>
```

I am getting the error: `missing ) after argument list` on this section of code using firefox 3.6.12.  The gallery still works but I get the error in fox and IE.  No error in chrome though.

Answer (score 8):

You're missing the `{` and `}` around your options object you're passing to `.fancybox()`.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.grouped_elements").fancybox({
                                     ^ here
       'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
       'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
       'speedIn' : 600,
       'speedOut' : 200, 
       'overlayShow' : false 
    });
    ^ and here
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be:
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.grouped_elements").fancybox( {'transitionIn' : 'elastic', 'transitionOut' : 'elastic', 'speedIn' : 600, 'speedOut' : 200, 'overlayShow' : false  });
    });

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a.grouped_elements").fancybox( **{**'transitionIn' : 'elastic', 'transitionOut' : 'elastic', 'speedIn' : 600, 'speedOut' : 200, 'overlayShow' : false ); });
```

You're missing a curly brace to open and close your set of object properties.

Answer (score 0):

u are missing  {} i have put it between xx xx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.grouped_elements").fancybox( xx{xx
       'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
       'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
       'speedIn' : 600,
       'speedOut' : 200, 
       'overlayShow' : false xx}xx);
  });
</script>
```